# How can I get rid of the the gap below absolutely positioned content?

Tags: css, css-position

I'm trying to bottom-align some variably sized linked images in a horizontally-aligned unordered list. My HTML + CSS, below, do the trick for the most part. There just one small gotcha: the gap below the image (http://jsfiddle.net/ymSvr/).  As you can see I'm using absolute positioning to get the image to stick to the bottom. But even with `bottom: 0` the image still doesn't quite go to the bottom.

Can someone please explain why this happens? And how can I resolve this?

**Markup**:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="outer">
      <div class="inner">
        <a href="javascrip:void(0)">
         <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-h-c-132-200-5.jpg" />
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="outer">
      <div class="inner">
        <a href="javascrip:void(0)">
         <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-h-c-132-165-4.jpg" />
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="outer">
      <div class="inner">
        <a href="javascrip:void(0)">
         <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-h-c-132-190-9.jpg" />
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**:

```
ul li { 
    display:inline-block;

}

.outer {
    background-color: #c0c0c0;
    display: block;
    height: 242px;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
}

.inner {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add the following code

```
img {
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ymSvr/1/

Comment: The simple solutions always seem to elude me! *face-palm*. Thx!